# Save parts of a string splitted in 3 different strings

Tags: c#, string, split

```
 /* string fecha_act = DateTime.Now.ToString("d/MM/yy"); */
date_act = "10-12-12"  
string[] splitting = date_act.Split('-');

foreach (string split in splitting)
{
    MessageBox.Show(split);
}
```

The above code shows a date in a string. That string will be splitted into three parts.
Said that, I need to save the three parts in three differents strings.

```
string day_act;
string month_act;
string year_act;
```

I've tried to doing it with a counter and a switch, but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?  It's so straightforward I suspect you've tried it already.

```
day_act = separando[0];
month_act = separando[1];
year_act = separando[2];
```

**Edit**

So you want alternate methods to `Split`?  Here are some:

- Use a variation of the `DateTime.Parse` method (as mentioned in other answers).
- Use a regular expression.

  ```
  var match = Regex.Match(date, @"(?<day>\d+)-(?<month>\d+)-(?<year>\d+)");
  day_act = match.Groups["day"].Value;
  month_act = match.Groups["month"].Value;
  year_act = match.Groups["year"].Value;
  ```

Comment: Yes, I've tried already. But I'm looking to do it in a way that doesn't imply using string arrays.

Answer (score 7):

```
string day_act;
string month_act;
string year_act;

string[] separando = date_act.Split('-');

day_act = separando[0];
month_act = separando[1];
year_act = separando[2];
```

Or, better yet, get yourself a real date object:

```
string date_act = "10-12-12";
var foo = DateTime.ParseExact(date_act, "MM-dd-yy", null);
```

Then you can look at properties like `foo.Day` or `foo.Month`.

Comment: Yes. Why re-invent the wheel when `DateTime` does it for us?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The `DateTime` object saved me hundreds of dollars on my car insurance.

Comment: The date in the first chunk of code was taken with `DateTime`: `string fecha_act = DateTime.Now.ToString("d/MM/yy");`

Comment: @CristianC. - So take your three string objects and just set them to the corresponding property of the `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers solve the question I asked, but to solve definitively my problem, I opted for a alternate solution that doesn't imply using a split at all. In this case, is a substring.

```
day_act = date_act.Substring(0,2);
month_act = date_act.Substring(3,2);
year_act = date_act.Substring(6,2);
```